# Standard Wreath Product and Sylow Subgroups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

A Sylow $p$-subgroup of $S_{p^r}$ is isomorphic with the standard Wreath Product $W(p,r) = (\cdots(C_p \wr C_p) \wr \cdots) \wr C_P)$, the number of factors being $r$.

I have a great doubt as to demonstrate this fact. Follow the solution proposed in Robinson's book (page 41/42) - A Couse in Group Theory

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to show that

1. $W(p, r)$ is, by construction, a permutation group of degree $p^{r}$, and then
2. the order of $W(p, r)$ is the $p$-part of $(p^{r})!$.

Comment: @ Andreas Sir.....i mean from ur answer  ..Number of generators for a $p-$sylow subgroups of $S_{p^2} = (p^2)!$  Is  it correct ?????

Comment: @ Andreas  sir..this 
 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2975891/some-diificult-problem-of-herstein-algebra-problem-5

Answer (score 0):

Let us prove that a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $S_{p^r}$ is of the required type by induction on $r$. The case $r=0$ is obvious. Assume that $S_{p^r}$ has as Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ of the sort described. Consider the permutation

$$\pi = (1,1+P^r, \ldots, 1+(p-1)p^r)(2,2+p^r, \ldots, 2+(p-1)p^r) \cdots (p^r,p^r+p^r, \ldots, p^r+(p-1)p^r). $$

Then $\pi \in S_{p^{r+1}}$ and $\pi^p = 1$. Let $S_{p^r}$ be regarded as a subgroup of $S_{p^{r+1}}$  through its action on $\{1,2, \ldots, p^r\}$, the other symbols being fixed. Then $P_i = \pi^{-i}P\pi^i$ affects only the symbols $j+ip^r$, where $j=1,2, \ldots, p^r$. Hence, $P=P_0, P_1, \ldots, P_{p-1}$ generate their direct product; also $\pi^{-1}P_i\pi = P_{i+1}, 0 \leq i < p-1$, and $\pi^{-1}P_{p-1}\pi = P_{0}$. Thus ***$<\pi, P> \cong P \wr <\pi>$***, the standard wreath product. It follows that $<\pi, P>$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $S_{p^{r+1}}$.

Comment: My doubts are why: $<\pi, P> \cong P \wr <\pi>$ and how can I verify that $\pi^{−1}P_i\pi = P_{i+1},0 \leq i< p−1$, and $\pi^{−1}P_{p-1}\pi = P_0$?

Comment: @AndreasCaranti do you know to answers my doubts? I need help, please. Thanks.

Comment: Is this part of your question?

Comment: Yes, @AlexanderGruber.

Comment: Then it should be a part of the question body, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a reference to a good explanation, then I would recommend Dixon and Mortimer's explanation in Example 2.6.1 on pages 48 and 49 of their book [Permutation Groups](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=4QDpFN6k61EC&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: Thank`s for the help @DaviWard